# UWP MvvmCross Bootstrap Class Not Working

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, nuget, mvvmcross, nuspec

**Setup:**

- MvvmCross Plugin Nuget:

  - Has a **portable class lib** w/typical PluginLoader.cs containing `mngr.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<...>()`
  - Has a **UWP class lib** w/typical Plugin.cs containing `Mvx.RegisterType<...>()` calls
  - Gets packed, and used in a UI proj (next)
- MvvmCross UI Proj:

  - Has a **portable class lib**, and UWP UI project
  - Has a **Bootstrap.cs file**, with typical `public class TTSPluginBootstrap : MvxPluginBootstrapAction< MyPlugin.TTS.PluginLoader >`
  - Has a **Setup.cs** file, w/typical `CreateApp` returning `Core.App()`

**Problem:**

- Including the Bootstrap.cs file in my UI proj causes `setup.Initialize()` to crash during `App::OnLaunched`
- Removing Bootstrap.cs allows UWP UI proj to run, but `Mvx.Resolve<...>()` calls cause a crash
- I have also tried including *.pri and *.rd.xml files during nuget packing, to no avail.

**Current Workarounds:**

- Delete Bootstrap.cs (or set build type to `Content`)
- Override `Setup::LoadPlugins` :

  - Either Manually force type registration with `Mvx.RegisterType<...>`, but this sort of defeats the purpose.
  - Or instantiate `MyPlugin.Uwp.Plugin`, and call `Load` on it

**Question(s):**

- If I am able to instantiate the Plugin class, and call Load on it, then how/why is the Bootstrap reflection failing to find PluginLoader?
- I have also tried the AoT way of declaring my Bootstrap class as well, so what is left to try?
- Is there a good reference somewhere on creating/consuming UWP MvvmCross plugins (e.g. NOT phone/store/8.1)?

Comment: Does anyone know of any working UWP UI apps that consume UWP nugets (e.g. NOT WindowsCommon,wpa8,win8) successfully?? @Cheesebaron has a [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins) plugin that can be **consumed** by UWP app, but only due to his WindowsCommon lib. The WindowsUWP portion of it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution (and steps took to get there):**

- Step 1: Cloned the MvvmCross repo, and updated branch to the version I was using in my projects
- Step 2: Removed NuGet references, and replaced w/local assembly references to MvvmCross clone
- Step 3: Stepped through code prior to `setup.Initialize()` call in App.xaml.cs
- **Finding:** Internally, MvvmCross uses reflection to get the `PluginLoader` instance, and subsequently to find the `Setup` class (containing `Load` method, in platform-specific plugin code).

  - This MvvmCross reflection has naming convention requirements.
- **The Fix:** When making a UWP-compatible MvvmCross plugin, ***your UWP class lib project MUST end with "WindowsUWP" (or "WindowsCommon", if portable)***

  - For me, this meant changing my NuGet's `Plugin.TTS.Uwp` namespace (and folders) to `Plugin.TTS.WindowsUwp`, and then re-packing and distributing my *.nupkg

Comment: If relevant documentation/tutorials are posted for MvvmCross UWP projects and plugins, please post, and I will gladly accept another answer which references that.